# Can Strionic Resonator re-direct Ulamog, The Ceaseless Hunger's exile ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-multiplayer

Let's say I have 15 copies of [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d) for a total of 16 triggers and I attack with [Ulamog, the Ceaseless Hunger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUlamog%2c%20the%20Ceaseless%20Hunger%5d) and copy its triggered ability to exile 20 cards from the top of defending players deck. Can I choose a different player or players to exile from or does it have to be defending player's deck?

Answer (score 12):

You cannot choose any other player than the defending player. [Ulamog, the Ceaseless Hunger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUlamog%2c%20the%20Ceaseless%20Hunger%5d) says:

> Whenever Ulamog, the Ceaseless Hunger attacks, defending player exiles the top twenty cards of their library.

As you can see, there is no word 'target' in the ability. That means that when copied with [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d), it doesn't allow you to choose another player.

The number of Strionic Resonators is irrelevant in this case. The ability works the same. You get more triggers though.

Answer (score 6):

You can't redirect the ability with [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d).  The ability on [Ulamog, the Ceaseless Hunger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUlamog%2c%20the%20Ceaseless%20Hunger%5d) does not specify the keyword "target" and you do not choose a target. You can copy the ability but it would only allow you to exile cards from the top of the defending player's library.

Comment: That's what I figured but wanted to ask. Thank you!